# Was sind direkte und indirekte Objekte?

Tags: grammar-identification, objects

Ich lese hier in Fragen immer wieder die Begriffe

- direktes Objekt
- indirektes Objekt

Diese Begriffe werden, meiner Beobachtung nach, (fast) ausschließlich von Leuten verwendet, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen.

Ich bin deutscher Muttersprachler, und kann mich nicht erinnern, diese Begriffe jemals in der Schule oder sonst irgendwo außerhalb dieses Forums gehört oder gelesen zu haben. Ich weiß zwar, was Objekte sind, aber mit den Attributen »direkt/indirekt« fange ich nichts an.

Ich kenne Genitivobjekte, Dativobjekte, Akkusativobjekte, und habe für den Gleichsetzungsnominativ auch schon die Bezeichnung *Nominativobjekt* gehört. Haben diese Bezeichnungen irgend etwas mit direkten und indirekten Objekten zu tun?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Die Begriffe *direktes* und *indirektes Objekt* entstammen an sich der englischen Grammatik und sind **im wesentlichen** deckungsgleich mit unseren Begriffen von *Akkusativ-* und *Dativobjekt*.

Das *direkte* Objekt in einem Satz ist per Definition dasjenige, das von der Handlung (also dem Prädikat) am stärksten beeinflusst wird - Im Deutschen also meistens das Akkusativobjekt. Das *indirekte* Objekt sind alle anderen - soweit vorhanden.

> Er schreibt ein Buch

Besitzt nur ein *direktes* Objekt, das Buch - im Akkusativ. Ein *indirektes* ist nicht vorhanden.

> Ich gebe dem Hund einen Knochen

Der Knochen ist hier das *direkte*, also Akkusativobjekt, der Hund das *indirekte*, also Dativobjekt.

Die deutsche Sprache ist allerdings ein wenig komplizierter als die englische. In vielen anderen als solchen trivialen Sätzen wie oben muss die Deckungsgleichheit nämlich nicht gegeben sein: Interessant bei der Betrachtung von Unterschieden zwischen den beiden Nomenklaturen sind also die Stellen, wo die Begrifflichkeiten auseinanderlaufen:

> Ich huldigte der Göttin

Hier ist die Göttin ein *direktes Objekt* (weil das einzige im Satz), allerdings im **Dativ**.

> Wir gedachten der Toten

Hier sind die Toten wieder ein *direktes Objekt*, allerdings im Genitiv.

> Der Unfall beraubte sie ihrer Schönheit

Hier haben wir als Beispiel ein *indirektes Objekt* im Genitiv.

Solche Ausnahmen, bei denen die Begrifflichkeiten auseinanderlaufen, werden allerdings zugegebenermassen immer seltener. Die deutsche Sprache vereinfacht sich hier mit der Zeit anscheinend immer mehr selbst.

Die Gleichsetzung von **direkt == Akkusativ** und **indirekt == Dativ** kann also für einen Fremdsprachler am Anfang eine Hilfe, allerdings, sobald die Sätze ein wenig komplizierter werden, eine ziemliche Hürde sein. Ich glaube, es wäre für einen Lernenden einfacher, gar nicht erst mit dieser Gleichsetzung anzufangen (wahrscheinlich mit ein Grund, warum man bei uns in der Schule die Begriffe *direktes* und *indirektes Objekt* gar nicht erst lernt, sondern gleich "richtig" mit dem Kasus bezeichnet).

Meiner Meinung nach sind die Begriffe nicht geeignet, um ein Objekt im Deutschen richtig zu bezeichnen.

(Der Vollständigkeit halber: Im Englischen gibt es im Übrigen noch eine *dritte* Objektklasse - das *Präpositionalobjekt* - Das sind Objekte, die mittels einer Präposition in den Satz "eingehängt" werden, und bei denen deswegen die Präposition den Kasus bestimmt. Ein mit einer Präposition in den Satz eingebundenes Nomen betrachtet die deutsche Grammatik i.A. überhaupt nicht als Objekt - sondern als *präpositionale Ergänzung*)

Answer (score 7):

Das direkte Objekt und das indirekte Objekt entsprechen grammatikalischen Begriffen, die ich in mehreren Sprachen gelernt habe:

- [lijdend voorwerp (lv)](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijdend_voorwerp) bzw. [meewerkend voorwerp](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meewerkend_voorwerp) im Niederländischen;
- den gleichen Begriffen in der Grammatik des Lateins (sechs Jahre Lateinunterricht auf Niederländisch ...);
- dem [complément d'objet direct (COD)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct) bzw. dem [complément d'objet indirect (COI)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_indirect) / dem [complément d'objet second](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_(grammaire)#Compl.C3.A9ment_d.27objet_second_ou_d.27attribution) im Französischen;
- und schließlich dem [direct object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#Types_of_objects) bzw. dem indirect object in der englischen Sprache.

Dies ist aus linguistischer Sicht eine vereinfachte Darstellung, aber sie funktioniert gut für eine "Schulgrammatik".

Das "direkte Objekt" wird oft definiert als dasjenige Satzglied in einem Aktivsatz, welches Subjekt wird, wenn man den Satz in einen Passivsatz umwandelt. Zum Beispiel:

> Der Arzt behandelt *den Patienten*. ["den Patienten" = direktes Objekt]

Passivsatz:

> Der Patient wird vom Arzt behandelt. ["Der Patient" = Subjekt]

Das "indirekt Objekt" wird bei Passivierung nicht Subjekt; man kann es meist identifizieren durch die Frage "wem?" Zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe *ihm* ein Buch geliehen. ["ihm" = indirektes Objekt (französisch: complément d'objet second); "ein Buch" = direktes Objekt]

Wenn man eine Sprache ohne Kasussystem als Muttersprache hat (z.B. Niederländisch, Französisch, English, Chinesisch), lernt man oft die *grobe Regel* (aber mehr dazu unten):

- direktes Objekt in Akkusativ umwandeln;
- indirektes Objekt in Dativ umwandeln.

Allerdings muss man dann auch lernen, dass ein Satzglied, das in der Muttersprache ein direktes Objekt ist, nich immer einem (deutschen) Akkusativobjekt entspricht. Nehmen wir zum Beispiel den niederlänsichen Satz

- Ik heb *hem* geholpen. (Englisch: I helped him.)

Dies ist ein Aktivsatz, den man in den folgenden Passivsatz umwandeln kann:

> Hij werd door mij geholpen.

"Hem" im ersten Satz wird als direktes Objekt (niederländische Schulgrammatik: "lijdend voorwerp") betrachtet. Die deutsche Übersetzung lautet aber

> Ich habe *ihm* geholfen.

Das direkte Objekt "hem" wird als "ihm" übersetzt, d.h. es wird zum Dativobjekt.

Comment: Ich kenne die Begriffe direktes und indirektes Objekt ganz sicher nicht aus dem Lateinunterricht - Wenn irgendeine Sprache ein ausgefeiltes Kasussystem hat, dann ist es doch ganz sicher Latein und braucht diese Hilfskonstrukte nicht.

Comment: @tofro Ja, Latein hat ein Kasussystem. Niederländisch aber nicht. Wie introduziert man den Akkusativ und den Dativ bei Schülern, dessen Muttersprache kein Kasussystem hat? Zum Beispiel, anhand von Begriffen, die sie schon aus dem Niederländischunterricht kennen.

Comment: Ja. Möglicherweise muss man von der Muttersprache ausgehen - Die Frage ist nur, ob den Schülern das wirklich hilft? Das direkte bzw. indirekte Objekt ist sehr viel weniger als eine Analogie zu Akkusativ, Dativ und den weiteren Fällen.

Answer (score 2):

Auch mir sind direkte und indirekte Objekte hauptsächlich aus dem Schulunterricht in Französisch und Englisch bekannt. In diesen Sprachen sind Kasusunterscheidungen weitgehend verlorengegangen. Wenn ich nun in einem Satz zwei Objekte habe, muss ich irgendwie klarstellen, welches welches ist. Im deutschen ist das ganz einfach:

> Ich stelle ihn dir vor.

Wir erkennen sofort, dass *er* vorgestellt wird und dass *du* die Ehre hast, eine neue Bekanntschaft machen zu dürfen. Die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder spielt dabei absolut keine Rolle, die folgenden Sätze sagen (mit teilweise leicht unterschiedlicher Betonung) das gleiche aus:

> Ich stelle dir ihn vor.
> Dir stelle ich ihn vor.
> Ihn stelle ich dir vor.

Die gleiche würzige Kürze bietet zum Beispiel das Finnische, wenngleich andere Fälle verwendet werden:

> Minä esittelen hänet sinulle.

Im Englischen oder Französischen kann man das nicht derart kurz aufschreiben, es müssen Fugenwörter eingesetzt werden:

> I’ll introduce him **to** you.
>
> Je le présente **à** toi.

(Französisch würde eigentlich die Form »Je te le présente« wählen, dabei geht aber die Partikel verloren, weswegen ich mich für diese, betontere Variante entschieden habe.)

Es fällt auf, dass in beiden Fällen ein Objekt *direkt* an das Verb angeschlossen wird, während das andere *indirekt,* das heißt mittels einer Präposition, angeschlossen wird. Dem direkten Objekt entspricht hierbei häufig – aber nicht stets – das deutsche Akkusativobjekt, während indirekte Objekte im Deutschen häufig – aber wieder nicht ausschließlich – als Dativobjekte umgesetzt werden.

Mir wurde hierbei erklärt, dass es genau dieser Anschlüss mit Präposition ist, der ein direktes von einem indirekten Objekt unterscheidet. Diese Unterscheidung ist im Deutschen – wie im Finnischen – wenig sinnvoll, denn in diesen Sprachen wird nur ein Bruchteil der Objekte indirekt angeschlossen. Daher sollten diese Begriffe im Deutschen vermieden werden.

Comment: Wenn du (in deinem zweiten Absatz) '"er" wird vorgestellt' schreibst, könnte man meinen, dass die Wortreihenfolge im Deutschen irgendwas zu bedeuten hätte. Man kann den Beispielsatz ohne Bedeutungsunterschied aber auch zu "Ich stelle dir ihn vor" umdrehen.