# Aktiv-Passiv Umsetzung eines Genitivobjekts

Tags: dative, genitive, passive

Die wohl-bekannte Grammatikbuch-Regel, um Aktiv ins Passiv umzusetzen, lautet im Grunde genommen so:

> Das Akkusativobjekt des Passivsatzes wird zum Subjekt des Passivsatzes.
>   Dabei bleiben Dativobjekte unverändert.

Beispiele:

> 1. Der Hund isst den Apfel. → Der Apfel wird  gegessen.
> 2. Er gab ihr die Adresse. → Ihr wurde die Adresse gegeben.

Wie setz man Genitiv um? Erwartet wird nicht dass jedes Genitivobjekt das erlaubt. *Dessen* bin ich mir bewusst. Doch Beispiele aus [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34000/was-sind-direkte-und-indirekte-objekte) sollten im Prinzip das erlauben:

> A1 Wir gedachten der Toten →
>   P1.a Der Toten wurde gedacht?
>   P1.b Die Toten wurden gedacht? (da verwechselt man aber *denken* und *gedenken*)
>
> A2. Der Unfall beraubte sie ihrer Schönheit →
>   P2a. Ihrer Schönheit wurde sie (vom/durch den Unfall) beraubt.
>   P2b. Ihre Schönheit wurde beraubt.

[Neulich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34000/was-sind-direkte-und-indirekte-objekte) wurde nach den Begriffen Direkt- und Indirektobjekt gefragt. Manchmal können Genitivobjekte als beides fungieren, so eine der Antworten da. Spielt das hier eine Rolle?

Comment: Müsste P2a nicht *Ihrer Schöhnheit wurde **sie** beraubt* heißen? P2b. Klingt für mich so als würde *die Schöhnheit* ihrer beraubt werden, nicht sie der Schönheit. Schönheit zu berauben ergibt doch irgendwie nicht so viel Sinn, oder bin ich gerade total auf dem Holzweg?

Comment: "Der Toten **wurde** gedacht" bzw. "Es wurde der Toten gedacht."

Comment: Und ich gebe @C5H8NNaO4 recht. "Ihrer Schönheit wurde sie beraubt." bzw. "Sie wurde ihrer Schönheit beraubt." und "Ihre Schönheit wurde ihr **geraubt**".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Passivkonstruktion mit Objekt-Subjekt-Tausch ist etwas, das intrinsischerweise nur Akkusativobjekte machen können. Das heißt, Genitivobjekte verhalten sich beim Umsetzen ins Passiv wie Präpositionalobjekte oder andere Satzglieder: Sie bleiben unverändert.

> Der Unfall<sup>{Nom}</sup> beraubte sie<sup>{Akk}</sup> ihrer Schönheit.<sup>{Gen}</sup>
>
> → Sie<sup>{Nom}</sup> wurde ihrer Schönheit<sup>{Gen}</sup> beraubt.

Hierbei können auch subjektlose Hauptsätze entstehen, wie dein anderes Beispiel zeigt:

> Wir<sup>{Nom}</sup> gedachten der Toten.<sup>{Gen}</sup>
>
> Der Toten<sup>{Gen}</sup> wurde gedacht.