Akkusativ oder Dativ mit Präposition "an"
Es geht um folgenden Beispielsatz:
"Das, was ihr an Gutem eignet."
Die Frage bezieht sich auf die Deklination von "Gut". Sollte wie im Satz der Dativ oder doch der Akkusativ angewendet werden? Das indirekte Objekt ist schließlich "ihr" und entsprechend im Dativ. Verlangt die Präposition "an" noch einmal den Dativ, um das direkte Objekt "Gut" ihr als Eigenschaft zukommen zu lassen? Wenn ja, wieso?

Es wäre gut, etwas Kontext hinzuzufügen, woher dieser Satz kommt. Ich würde das als altmodisch oder poetisch ansehen. Das Konzept von direkten oder indirekten Objekten stammt aus anderen Sprachen, die kein Kasus-System wie im Deutschen haben. Die Regel Akkusativ = direkt, Dativ = indirekt ist eine vereinfachte Erklärung, die nicht immer stimmt. siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34000/43666

In Ergänzung zum Kommentar oben: Die "Regel" Akkusativ = direkt, Dativ = indirekt führt bei Anwesenheit von Präpositionen komplett in die Irre.

Zunächst eine Klarstellung: "direktes Objekt" und "indirektes Objekt" gibt es nicht. Die sind das grammatikalische Äquivalent von Phlogiston.
Zur Frage selbst: der Dativ ist korrekt und der Satz, so, wie er zitiert ist, ebenfalls. Tatsächlich liegt der Frage nämlich ein weiteres Mißverständnis zugrunde: die gesamte Konstruktion "an Gutem" ist nämlich ein Nominativ, die Subjektgruppe des Nebensatzes, die auf das einleitende "das" zurückverweist. Nur das Nomen darin ist, aufgrund der Rektion des "an", ein Dativ.
Vergleichsweise, derselbe Satzteil ohne "an":

was ihr (wer?) Gutes eignet.
das Gute, das ihr eignet.

Lediglich das "an" verlangt den Dativ, weil es sich - Bezüge sind ursprünglich immer örtlich und werden dann entweder direkt oder im übertragenen Sinn verwendet - um einen Ort handelt, wie etwa auch:

an dem Ort

